# Naturality of a Kunneth formula for cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology

Let $X,Y$ be CW complexes. By Kunneth formula, we have a group isomorphim
$$ H^n(X\times Y;G) \cong \oplus_{p+q=n} H^p(X;H^q(Y;G))$$
Is there a natural map realizing this isomorphism?

Comment: what happened to the other answer which was below? I'd be interested to know whether the argument was flawed, or any reason why it was deleted. (please?)

Comment: Isn't it the eilenberg-zilber map? On the level of chains we have $C^n(X \times Y) \rightarrow (C^*(X) \otimes C^*(Y))^n = \oplus_{p+q = n} C^p(X) \otimes C^q(Y)$. The latter is a chain complex that computes the $p$-th cohomology of $X$ with coefficients in the $q$-th cohomology (just like how $C^*(X) \otimes G$ computes cohomology of $X$ with coefficients in $G$)

Comment: @user125763 I believe the argument in that previous answer has a flaw, because the Serre's spectral sequence only gives a filtration instead of a direct sum structure. Maybe the author deleted it.

Comment: @EldenElmanto Why is the cohomology of $\oplus _{p+q=n}C^p(X)\otimes C^q(Y)$ the $p$-th cohomology of $X$ with coefficient $H^q(Y)$? This is exactly what I need. Is it a standard result? Do you have a reference for it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see. Maybe considering the filtrations coming from both projections turns them into a direct sum decomposition?

Comment: We may have natural quasi-isomorphism $C^*(X\times Y)\to C^*(X)\otimes C^*(Y)$, which is easy to define by acyclic models, we may have $H^*(C^*(X)\otimes C^*(Y))=H_*(Hom(C_*(X), Hom(C_*(Y), G)))$, but the problem is I don't think you can really go farther from here without introducing an unaturallity. Now, you can aurgue that $Map(-, K(G, n))=\prod K(H^{n-p}(-, G), p)$, which definitely gives naturality in one variable, but I'm not sure you can get full naturality through this either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came across this question in my 1961 DPhil Thesis;   this was written up in two papers which are available from my [Publication List](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/publicfull.htm),

[3]. ``Cohomology with chains as coefficients'', *Proc. London Math. Soc*. (3) 14 (1964), 545-565.

[4]. ``On K\"{u}nneth suspensions'', *Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc.* 60 (1964) 713-720.

It is  shown in the first paper that the isomorphism could be chosen to be natural with respect to maps of $X$ but **not** with respect to maps of either $Y$ or of $G$. The naturality was important for the second paper, which was poorly titled: it should have been something like "$k$-invariants of function spaces". Paper [3] also contains as an Appendix formulae for this isomorphism in some special cases

The aim of this work was to investigate the Postnikov system of $Y^X$ by induction on the Postnikov system of $Y$. Michael Barratt suggested this as another way of determining in some cases the extensions  involved in his work on exact sequences of track groups;  such a determination in his paper "Track Groups II"  used Whitney tube systems!

.